# Get error: Type 'string[] | null' is not assignable to type 'string[]' while using an Observable and async pipe

Tags: angular, observable, async-pipe

I can see there are many posts on similar, but not quite the same as my VERY simple situation.

I have a custom component (not mine) that has a `string[]` input.

Now, when using this, if I have the following, all is fine

```
//TS
public data = []


// HTML
<my-component [data]="data"></my-component>
```

However, if I have it to an observable, and even initialize it

```
// TS
public data: Observable<string[]> = of([]);

// HTML
<my-component [data]="data | async"></my-component>
```

I get

```
Type 'string[] | null' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ngtsc(2322)
```

How can I use observable with the async pipe for component input?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and provide a default value.

```
<my-component [data]="(data | async) ?? []"></my-component>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n3scxj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, it could be the answer. Seems a pity we would now have to do that everywhere, as opposed to the previous "clean" syntax.